# click event did not fired first click on the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the following code snippet to invoke the click event of a document:

```
$(document).bind("click", $.proxy(proxy._cellClickHandler, proxy));

_cellClickHandler: function (e) {
            var $target = $(e.target),
                row = $target.closest('tr'),
                proxy = this,
                args = {},
                currentData,
                index;
}
```

Clicking it the first time does not fire the event. On the second click it invokes correctly. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: wrap it inside $(document).ready()

Comment: 25 QUESTIONS AND NOT ACCEPTED ANSWERS AT ALL!? You really should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) some answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'on' (http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
var proxy= {
  _cellClickHandler: function (e) {
            var $target = $(e.target),
                row = $target.closest('tr'),
                proxy = this,
                args = {},
                currentData,
                index;
  }
}

$(document).on("click", $.proxy(proxy._cellClickHandler, proxy));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.live` Click if you are not using the updated jquery 1.9

```
$(document).live("click", $.proxy(proxy._cellClickHandler, proxy));
```

Comment: Then why the second click working.?

Comment: Probably the element is loading dynamically. DOM is unable to register it in some way and therefore element might not be found.

Comment: I am not the asker.. Just asked, ok if we assume that the element is not present while registering the event, Then why it is working on the second click. Two possibilities, either it should work correctly or it should not work completely. I think there might be some other problem with OP's code.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy ya i got that later. The asker shared first four letters of your name i got confused. and to answer that question DOM and JS have to co-related. DOM has to load before JS. Dynamic elements tend to take time and posibility is that during second click that element is available. But again depends on the code.

Comment: @Makrand - Or `.on` in new versions.